# VBS working from all pcs except 1. Works from shortcut with argument though

Tags: windows-10, vbscript

In the past I have used a very simple script:

```
set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
CreateObject("Wscript.Shell").RUN "C:\windows\system32\taskkill.exe /F /IM ""msedge.exe"" /T",0,True
```

To kill `msedge`. This works from all the pcs in my office except one where it returns an error like `(null): 0xfffffffe` in line 2 char 1. The code has been tested by multiple systems and works great apart from 1 pc.

I suspect a policy is different or a permission maybe. Running the argument via wscript shortcut does the trick so not sure what gives...

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the error? There may be a clue there that's missing from your description of the error. It might help to re-register vbscript.dll. Are all machines running 64 bit Windows? Please also note that the usual corporate approach is that if you can't fix it quickly, and it's only happening on one machine, you re-image and move on.

Comment: I tried re-registering the vbscript.dll but no luck there. IT also moved the dll from another computer that the vbs was working but still nothing, same error. At this point we will be re-imaging from another working pc as you suggested.

Voila the error

https://imgur.com/a/Sf4rYtm

Comment: You could first try a [Repair Install](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/16397-repair-install-windows-10-place-upgrade.html).

Comment: Already did a repair in hard drive, policies etc. Nothing works :(

Answer (score 0):

It may be a permission issue. I would simplify the troubleshooting by eliminating VBScript from the equation. Make a batch file that contains this one line and use that instead of the VBScript file.

**KillEdge.cmd**

```
taskkill /f /im msedge.exe /t
```

Try that on the same machine and let us know the results.

Please note that you will get permission errors on some msedge.exe processes regardless of the script used if you're running non-elevated. You will need to "Run as Administrator" in order to kill all msedge.exe processes.

Comment: Bat files work ok, already tested it no issue. Using this VBScript is my only option for the moment because the procedure has been validated and is part of a much bigger tree of events. In fact I get the same error trying all system32 exe as like cmd, calculator etc. Same error nevertheless. I can't use utilities from system32 via a vbs file. I repeat this is not an issue with the vbs, it works in all other pcs and all of them have the same permissions :S